# 'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'width'

Tags: python, class

So I am just starting to use the classes portion of python and I've constructed a class and main program that my text book asked me to write.  It looks ok to me but I keep getting an error saying that my class doesn't have this specific attribute, which is weird because it should.  Now this is just a simple Rectangle, find the perimeter and area program.  So it is nothing too complicated.  But maybe you guys can see something I cannot.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length = 1, width = 1):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def setWidth(self, width):
        self.width = width

    def setLength(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def getPerimeter(self):
        return (2 * self.length) + (2 * self.width)

    def getArea(self):
        return self.length * self.width
```

---

Here is the actual main program

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle

recWidth = eval(input("Enter the length of the rectangle: "))
recLength = eval(input("Enter the width of the rectangle: "))
x = Rectangle()
y = Rectangle()
x.width(recWidth)
x.length(recLength)
print("The perimeter of a rectangle with a width of", recWidth,
      " units and a length of ", recLength, " units is ", x.getPerimeter(), ".")
```

Thanks I hope I have provided enough information to help formulate a valid question.

Comment: Don't use `eval` if all you need is `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the methods `width` and `length` with 2 parameters (x and recWidth/recLength) when they are simply variables. You either meant to do this:

```
x.width   # get the width of the Rectangle
x.length  # get the height of the Rectangle
```

OR

```
x.setWidth(recWidth)     # set the width of the Rectangle
x.setLength(recLength)   # set the height of the Rectangle
```